# Studying mathematics abroad - specifically France

Tags: soft-question

I have tried to avoid asking a "soft question" on here because I'm not sure if they are appreciated or not.  However, this is one that has been bothering me.  I was recently talking to a few friends of mine about my desire to study in France.  I have a B.S. in Math, and am working towards a Master's degree.

We poked our noses around and posted various threads on different websites.  So far we have gotten a lot of advice such as "Don't waste your time."  Or other things such as "French universities have terrible math programs."  However, constructive advice has eluded our questions.  We are just generally met with antagonism towards the idea of studying in France.

My question is specifically this: what is a reasonable French university at which I can study mathematics.  I would like to study in France.  I have a reasonably strong command of the language.  However, I may be hamstrung by the fact that I had only had ok/good grades in my math courses.  Lot's of B's and B+'s.  Anyway, I'm not looking for the oppurtunity to study at the grande ecoles.  At the same time, I would not want to go to their equivalent  of some sort of third-rate state university.  I'm just interested in trying to seek out an oppurtunity to be abroad while studying mathematics.

Comment: Perhaps this is the place where Eric Naslund should be commenting ; he is a student at UBC who is currently doing his last year of B.S. at Ecole Polytechnique de Paris as we speak. @Eric Naslund : You gotta answer this one =)

Comment: That would be nice to have some real feedback.  I'm just looking for a master's program at a French university that's reasonably good.  I'm assuming that French universities have a "range" from very, more, less, not very competitive admissions.

Comment: The first warning I want to make is that the splitting points (=degrees) of a person's math education vary from one country to another. I don't know about France, but for example my Uni confers two levels of undergraduate degrees, and the upper one is translated as M.Sc. In terms of math exposure that master's degree is somewhere between a US bachelor or master's degree depending on A) how serious the student here was with his/her selectives and B) how much ivy your US college has. If you look for graduate programs, they usually mean doctorate only, and then a lot of B's becomes a problem.

Comment: It would help if you state your field of interest, so recommendations can be more tailored.

Comment: Pure mathematics, specifically problems that exist within Topology and Geometry.

Comment: the ENS Lyon has a very good group of geometers, as does the university of grenoble. also, as gunnar pointed out, you'll have all the choice you want in paris

Comment: I guess I was very scared about even attempting to apply to a normal university in Paris (or even France).  I was told by a professor I had as an undergraduate that European universities were more elite.  As such, they are far more difficult to get into.  Also, I was worried because I was not sure how to translate my US GPA to it's French equivalent.

Comment: @EMKA Don't worry, you're much more likely to get into any university than not. One thing you should look into is if there is some sort of an international office at your current university. The people there should be able to tell you about and help you with the administrative hoops you need to jump through during the application process (i.e. translating the GPA, etc.). This might also be a good time to see if there are any French professors in your department, or anyone who studied in France, who can help you out.

Comment: This is far more reassuring than the very elite view that was taught to me by a few professors.  Because of them, I assumed that only the very best could even dream of a university education in Europe.  I will probably start the process of applying soon.  I just have to do some research about the various universities - I'm certain I should be able to find someone who is more knowledgeable about the universities. I will check at my university if there is someone familiar with the administrative stuff.  I did notice that French universities require a lot for my application.

Comment: *opportunity is misspelled

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki Do you know what's the best universities in France to study algebraic topology?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I came to France to study after my bachelor's (which I did in Iceland). So far I've done my master's here and am finishing my PhD. I've spent my time here at the university in Grenoble.

I mostly concur with Glougloubarbaki. If your main objective is to study math, then try to go to a grande école, or go directly to a "Master 2" in a public university. This is the second year of masters, where you start specializing. The difference in dedication and skills of the students in public universities vs. grands écoles levels out during the M2.

If you want to take some time to see more of the culture and the country, then do the first year of master's in a public university as well, but know that if your background is strong you won't profit much from it.

As was already said, it is non-trivial to get into a grand école, but I recommend you try. You have about a 90% chance to get into any public university you want. I suspect the 10% failure rate is mostly due to papers getting lost along the way.

With these caveats in place, the question of which university to go to starts to depend an awful lot on what field you want to study for your masters. Different universities have different research groups. Paris has the advantage of having a lot of maths departments, so there is choice there, but other cities have good groups as well. For example, Grenoble has active groups in topology and algebraic geometry, some good analysis is coming out of Toulouse, etc. We might be able to give you some more detailed pointers if you tell us what you're interested in.

Comment: Gunnar: your enumeration of *active groups* in Grenoble is cute.

Comment: @Didier: I meant no offence, I was just talking about the groups I know well.

Answer (score 12):

The French system is a bit weird. The best places to go are not the university, but the so-called [«grandes écoles»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandes_%C3%A9coles). So if you want the best, you should go to either the Ecole Normale Supérieure of Paris, or the the Ecole Normale Supérieure of Lyon, or the Ecole Normale Supérieure of Cachan or the Ecole Polytechnique. Beware that the selection level is quite high.

Now the second best places to go are big universities, which are not so bad. I recommend Jussieu (Université Paris 7), or Chevaleret (Paris 6). The main difference is that there is almost no selection at the first year undergrad level, whereas for the «grandes écoles» the selection is a huge national exam 2 years after high school... (you have to be in the first 200 out of several thousands to be in the ones I mentioned).

Hope that helps ! You should come, France is a nice country to study in ! =)

Comment: How is the competitiveness of admissions at such places.  I'm not saying that my grades are terrible (B+'s and B's), but I am aware that they are not amazing either.  Would places like Paris 6 and Paris 7 be reasonable places to apply to for a master's degree?

Comment: I don't know about the admission rate for foreign students. but I can tell you the level at Paris 6 in master 2 (I didn't see that at first) is very good, as lots of students from the Grandes Ecoles I mentionned go to this master when they're interested in academics. (it's a bit less true for paris 7). so expect to work hard !

Comment: @emka I don't know whether you're still interested, but ENS Paris has a program called [sélection internationale](http://www.ens.fr/admission/selection-internationale/) which is suitable for international students. No French is required before the examination.

Comment: And for the answer: international students are not usually selected through «concour», but a specific selection procedure is organized by ENS Ulm and X, respectively, as far as I know.

Answer (score 5):

French system is unique regarding other countries in that fact that it is generally considered as a shame and a disgrace for a student to enter at 1st year of French public universities. This means that this student has failed to all the 'Grandes Ecoles' entry tests (Big Schools) but also to all the less prestigious engineering schools and the technology institutes - which are really like a thousands -

The paradox is that the teachers in these public universities come often themselves from the Elite Grandes Ecoles.

The other paradox is that a great deal of very good mathematician and scientists comes from public University despite this bad reputation.

For example Grothendieck did not come from the Ecole Normale Superieure but directly from the university of Montpellier.

At Phd level , students from Grandes Ecoles often enter directly public University.

Note that the mathematics taught at Msc level in Parisian Universities are often themselves quite good.

The French system is based on a sort of cruel and hard elitism which ages from Napoleon !st and most of the Grandes Ecoles do not provide Mathematicians but Engineers. Almost all Elite French Mathematicians come from one only ultra-selective school which is the Ecole Normale Superieure of Ulm.

This system seems a bit outdated by now and frankly a bit stupid ( I am from one of the top Grandes Ecoles myself )

With regards to the U.S system, the U.S system is for me unable to produce mathematicians on their ground, they need to constantly import them either from India, China, Russia or even France.

I wish we all could be like Grothendieck!

Comment: I wish there are more men like Grothendieck!

Comment: Grothendieck attended seminars from Ecole Normale Superieure (ENS) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck

Comment: @raymond That not relevant to where Grothendieck got his education

Comment: @Zee I was just pointing out despite Grothendieck not graduating from the Ecole Normale Superieure, he attended seminars there.